# In PowerBI I have a matrix visual and a slicer. The slicer contains the vendor I want to filter the first 5 rows according to slicer, except brand

Tags: powerbi

In `PowerBI` I have a matrix visual and a slicer. The slicer contains the vendor I want to filter the first 5 rows according to slicer, except brand row in the sixth row.

[image: 1]

Comment: Show your expected output. Also sample data in tabular format is required so that people can copy the data.